# Left outer join relation between Datasets

Tags: .net, ado.net

I have two datasets named dataset1,dataset2.  I want put the left outer join relation between them.

eg:dataset1 left outer join dataset2

Comment: you mean two datasets or datatables ?. Show some code that will help us analyze how much you have tried on your part .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear so there are at least two possible answers.

If you do indeed have two different [`DataSet`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) and they need to stay as separate `DataSet`s then you could use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) ([with Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx)) to create a left outer join.  Here are a couple of blog post explaining how to create left outer joins using LINQ ([one](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/c-left-outer-joins-with-linq/) and [two](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/10/15/my-500th-post-left-outer-joins-with-linq.aspx)).  Your code will probably look something along the lines of

```cs
var joinResult = from ds1Row in dataset1.Tables["some table"]
                 join ds2Row in dataset2.Tables["some other table"]
                 on ds1Row.Field<T>("some column") equals ds2Row.Field<T>("some other column") into tmpResult
                 from resultRow in tmpResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new 
                 {
                   //select whatever information you want
                   column1 = ds1Row.Field<T>("name column"),
                   column2 = ds1Row.Field<T>("name column"),
                   column3 = ds2Row.Field<T>("name column")
                 };
```

If you really meant doing a join between two [`DataTable`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) or you can combine two DataSets into a single DataSet using the [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135417.aspx) method and then [create a relationship between any two tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  Your code will look something along the lines of:

```cs
mergedDataset.Relations.Add("relation name",
mergedDataset.Tables["some table"].Columns["some column"],
mergedDataset.Tables["some other table"].Columns["some other column"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only create a DataRelation between two tables in the same DataSet. What you will need to do is use the Merge method to bring the two datasets together e.g.

```
DataSet1.Merge(DataSet2)
```

Then you can create a DataRelation between the two tables by running

```
DataSet1.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("myRelationship",DataTable1.Columns("ID"),DataTable2.Columns("ID")))
```

Answer (score 0):

[INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOINS and RIGHT OUTER JOIN for DataTables](http://victormaceda.wordpress.com/2007/07/11/inner-join-left-outer-joins-and-right-outer-join-for-datatables/)

the link has a good vb program that does outer join. You can use it if you use in your vb.net , check it out.

[DataTable Relational Operators in C# - JOIN Method](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/archive/2004/01/20/748.aspx)

both codes are self explanatory and as Duncan said you can only do this using data tables are not using two separate data sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the result, I would suggest using LINQ to DataSets, which allows you to use any of the LINQ operators to query and join two DataTables/DataSets.

Erick